# Mongoose find with reference to object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a find inside a loop:

```javascript
for(var idx in items){
    var item = items[idx];

    Model.find({'_id': item.id}, function(err, matches){
          console.log(item); // Points to the last item in items instead of
                             // expected item, since find is asynchronous
    });
}
```

As you see, since find is asynchronous I can't get a solid reference to the `item` var.

I could go ahead and manually look for it again in the `items` array by the matched object inside the callback but that just doesn't seems like an effective approach.

If there would be any way to "attach" an object to the call so I could get it back with the callback that would be awesome.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a closure since the loop, and `item` with it, will be done before any callback is called.

```
for(var idx in items){
  (function(item){
    Model.find({'_id': item.id}, function(err, matches){
      console.log(item);
    });
  })(items[idx]);
}
```

Which should be pretty much the same as the following (assuming items is an array):

```
items.forEach(function(item){
  Model.find({'_id': item.id}, function(err, matches){
    console.log(item);
  });
})(items[idx]);
```

Comment: Thanks! The second example is exactly what I needed.